# How is it I am unable to create a new index method?

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I am attempting to add a new item to the to-do list. However, the new index is throwing an error. What am I missing?

_navbar.html.erb file:

```
<%= render "form_index %>
```

lists_controller.rb file:

```
def index
    @lists = List.all
    @list = List.new
   end

def new
    @list = List.new
  end
```

_form_index.html.erb file:

```
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <%= f.text_field :description, class: "form-control mr-sm-2" %>
  <%= f.submit "Add To-Do Item", class: "btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" %>
<% end %>
```

My confusion resides within this error message:

undefined local variable or method `list' for #ActionView::Base:0x0000000002e2e8>

Did you mean?  @list
@lists

```
<%= form_with(mode: list) do |form| %>
   <% if list.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this list from being saved:</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a few @ signs and my text field was supposed to be set its true field which is "item"

_form_index.html.erb file should have been:

```
<div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <%= form.text_field :item, class: "form-control mr-sm-2" %>
  <%= form.submit "Add To-Do Item", class: "btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" %>
<% end %>
```

The following error:
undefined local variable or method `list' for #ActionView::Base:0x0000000002e2e8>

Did you mean? @list
@lists

was telling me to go beyond the surface in my _form_index.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_with(model: @list) do |form| %>
  <% if @list.errors.any? %>
    <h2><%= pluralize(list.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this list from being saved:</h2>
```

I am such a newbie and I love it more and more everyday. I have definitely learned to appreciate errors. I call often tell myself "read the screen".